# How to use quaternions to describe a rotation angle which is more than 360 degrees？

Tags: c++, math, graphics

I'm trying to use quaternions to do rotation animation.
My algorithm creates Quaternions, and slerps every frame.
Here is my code to construct a quaternion by the axis and the rotation angle.

```
template <typename U>
Quaternion(Vector3<U> vec, const float& angle)
{
    vec.normalize();
    float cosa = cos(angle/2);
    float sina = sin(angle/2);
    w = cosa;
    x = sina * vec.x;
    y = sina * vec.y;
    z = sina * vec.z;
}
```

Then I found that when I tried to rotate 4π radians, the animation does not work because the quaternion I created is equivalent to 0 degrees.
I wonder if quaternions can represent rotations over 360 degrees? Or is my animation algorithm in need of improvement?

Comment: *"I tried to rotate 4π degrees"* You mean 4π radians? `sin` and `cos` take radians, not degrees.

Comment: Yes, I mean radians. Sorry I'm not good at English.

Comment: Btw., it is unusual what you're trying to do. Suppose, that you have two rotations (A, B). Both have a large rotation (>360) around some axis. What do you expect, how can one interpolate between them, if not the trivial one (ignoring the "excess" rotation, and treat the rotation something like "mod 360", I mean use just the end-pose of the rotation)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wonder if quaternions can represent rotations over 360 degrees?

No, it can not.

Quaternions between the range [360;720] will treated as rotations at the other direction: [-360;0].

And quaternions between the range [720*k; 720*(k+1)] will be treated as rotations [0;720].

If you use slerp for this kind of animation, quaternions are not good for them.

Quaternions can only slerp between angles which are smaller than 360.

If you still want to do this, use a different representation, like axis-angle.

Comment: Another possibility is to split the rotation into circle sectors all of which below the supremum angle.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to use axis-angle to do the animation.

Answer (score 1):

Rotating be 360 degrees **is** the same as rotating by 0 degrees. To rotate by an angle `alpha` bigger than 360 simply rotate by `alpha-360` or more general by `alpha % 360`.

(360 used as synonym for `2pi`, you need to take care about degree vs radians of course. And not sure if thats a typo, but `360` degree is `2pi` not `4pi`)

PS: Actually I think there is nothing wrong with your code, and maybe you dont have to change anything. It's just your expectations that were wrong: You should get the same for a rotation by 4pi as for a rotation by 0.

Comment: But with animation it's different.It works well when I use the euler angle.

Comment: @M.Zhao what is missing actually is a case where it does not work well. What you describe in your question is not really a problem, but what you get is just expected

Answer (score 1):

Think of quaternions as instant rotations - rotating by 4π radians instantly is the same as doing nothing.

This is not what you want when you animate rotation of 4π radians over 20 seconds. You can solve it by creating an Euler Vector (a 3D vector whose direction represents the axis of rotation, same as in quaternion, while its length represents the speed/angle of the rotation), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation. Later, multiply it by time passed and convert it into quaternion or 3D matrix depending on what your graphics wants.